# Run inner join query in Grafana where datasource is influx

Tags: grafana, influxdb

I need to run inner join query in Grafana where datasource is InfluxDB.
In sql query will be:

```
SELECT t.status,count(t.taskName) FROM TasksStatus t 
INNER JOIN TasksStatus  s 
ON t.taskName = s.taskName 
WHERE t.modified > s.modified
GROUP BY t.status;
```

Getting Error while running in grafana
InfluxDB Error: error parsing query: found t, expected ; at line 1, char 71

Answer (score 0):

https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v1.8/query_language/

> InfluxQL, the InfluxDB SQL-like query language

It is only SQL-like, but it not a SQL language. InfluxQL doc doesn't mention any support for `INNER JOIN`, so it is not suported by InfluxQL.

Comment: Thanks @JanGaraj , I have gone through the documentation and it says Inner join not supported. Can you please suggest any workaround for above query?